# regex is making Angular compile super slow

Tags: angular, regex

Angular won't compile a service that has 142 regex expressions. The first fifty were OK but then each additional regex slows down compilation. It's stopped at 77 (`Generating browser application bundles...`).

The service transcribes Spanish words into the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA). Here's a sample of the code.

```js
// Rule 12, 'v'
  // if the word includes 'v'
  if (word.includes('v')) {
    rulesArray.push('12');

    // if 'v' is the first letter
    if (word.charAt(0) === 'v') {
      ipaWord = ipaWord.replace('v', '7'); // replace 'v' with '7'
    }

    // if word includes 'mv'
    if (word.includes('mv')) {
      regexp = /mv/gi
      ipaWord = ipaWord.replace(regexp, 'm7'); // replace 'mv' with 'm7'
    }

    // if word includes 'nv'
    if (word.includes('nv')) {
      regexp = /nv/gi
      ipaWord = ipaWord.replace(regexp, 'n7');  // replace 'nv' with 'n7'
    }

    regexp = /v/gi
    ipaWord = ipaWord.replace(regexp, 'β'); // replace 'v' with 'β' in all other cases

    regexp = /7/gi
    ipaWord = ipaWord.replace(regexp, 'b');  // restore 'b'
  } // close Rule 12, if the word includes 'v'
```

I wrote this code a few years ago for Cloud Functions for Firebase, it's worked fine there. I just figured I could save a network call and make my app run faster by making this a service in Angular (synchronous) instead of calling the cloud function (async).

Am I doing something wrong or does Angular hate regex expressions?

Activity Monitor shows the CPU is 65% idle, low memory pressure, and low energy, disk, and network activity. I hear the fan running hard and I can feel the computer is hot. Is there a way to use Chrome Dev Tools to see what code is stopped?

Visual Studio Code has problems with the same file. The original file is JavaScript and I'm converting it to TypeScript, which requires declaring variables at the top. VSCode throws errors saying that variables haven't been declared, when the variables are declared at the top. Quitting and restarting TypeScript fixes the errors.

If I were a genius I might rewrite the 142 regex expressions into a single super regex expression, but that would unreadable by anyone else.

Comment: The angular CLI being a nodejs application, you should be able to use the [nodejs debugging support](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started) to debug its execution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by dividing the file into sixteen files.

```js
    word = spanishPhonologyRule1(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule13(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule12(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule2(word, shortAccent) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule3(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule4(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule11(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule5(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule6(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule7(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule8(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule9(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule10(word) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule14(word, shortAccent) as string;
    word = spanishPhonologyRule15(word, shortAccent) as string;
```

I tried moving the file to Cloud Functions for Firebase but that compiler slowed down and stopped too. The original JavaScript file compiled in Cloud Functions without a problem. The problem appears to be that TypeScript can't compile more than 60 or 70 regex expressions, when JavaScript compiles 100+ regex expressions without slowing down.